# (Hackerearth) Random occurence of NZEC with nested static Java classes (Java 8)

Tags: java

HackerEarth seems to randomly throw NZEC errors whenever I run programs that contain nested static classes. This is the Java 8 compiler.

Sometimes all the test cases go through, but there will often be one test case that returns the error, and the cases that return the error are never consistent. This happens even for simple, non memory-intensive tasks and will never happen on my computer's Eclipse compiler. This question is Monk and Sorting Algorithm.

Is there a way to fix this error, or if it cannot be circumvented, another way to make custom variable types without relying on nested static classes?

Here is the error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestClass$pack
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestClass$pack
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

And here is the program snippet containing the static class.

```
class TestClass {
    static class pack{
        long[] arr;
        int[] weight;
    }
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
//main body follows
```

I doubt it will help much, but the rest of the main code is here:

```
    int l;       //variable declaration
    int ivalue = 1;
    int totalweight = 0;
    int chunkstart;
    int chunkend;
    long chunkstartmul;
    long chunkendmul;
    long tmp;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    l = sc.nextInt();     //records input length and array
    pack packager = new pack();
    packager.arr = new long[l];
    packager.weight = new int[l];
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        packager.arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
    }
    sc.close();

    do {             
        chunkstart = 5 * ivalue;          //calculates and assigns weight values
        chunkstartmul = (long)Math.pow(10, chunkstart);
        chunkend = (5 * (ivalue - 1));
        chunkendmul = (long)Math.pow(10, chunkend);
        totalweight = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            tmp = packager.arr[i] % chunkstartmul;
            tmp = (tmp - (tmp % chunkendmul)) / chunkendmul;
            packager.weight[i] = (int)tmp;
            totalweight += tmp;
            tmp = 0;
        }
        if (totalweight == 0){
            break;
        }

        packager = mergesort(packager);     //merge sort
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {       //prints output
            System.out.print(packager.arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        ivalue++;     //increments ivalue, causing next loop to select the next 5 digits
    } while(true);
}
static pack mergesort(pack a) {                //mergesort
    int l = a.weight.length;
    if(l == 1) {
        return a;
    }

    int bl = (int)Math.floor(l/2);
    int cl = l - bl;
    pack b = new pack();
    pack c = new pack();
    b.arr = new long[bl];
    b.weight = new int[bl];
    c.arr = new long[cl];
    c.weight = new int[cl];

    for(int i = 0; i < bl; i++) {
        b.arr[i] = a.arr[i];
        b.weight[i] = a.weight[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < cl; i++) {
        c.arr[i] = a.arr[bl + i];
        c.weight[i] = a.weight[bl + i];
    }

    b = mergesort(b);
    c = mergesort(c);

    return merge(b, c);
}

static pack merge(pack b, pack c) {          //merging halves
    int bl = b.weight.length;
    int cl = c.weight.length;

    pack d = new pack();
    d.arr = new long[bl + cl];
    d.weight = new int[bl + cl];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i < bl && j < cl) {
        if(b.weight[i] > c.weight[j]) {
            d.weight[i + j] = c.weight[j];
            d.arr[i + j] = c.arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            d.weight[i + j] = b.weight[i];
            d.arr[i + j] = b.arr[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    while(j < cl) {
        d.weight[i + j] = c.weight[j];
        d.arr[i + j] = c.arr[j];
        j++;
    }
    while(i < bl) {
        d.weight[i + j] = b.weight[i];
        d.arr[i + j] = b.arr[i];
        i++;
    }

    return d;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you find a solution. I seem to be running into the same issue on Hackerearth but on a different problem.

Comment: I'll post here if I find a solution, but for now I just avoid nested static classes entirely and instead just use another class outside the public class and call it with `new.

Comment: this is not the problem-specific issue, it happens with almost every problem. I am using Custom class for input-output and getting the same error.